# Laravel Eloquent get results grouped by days

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I currently have a table of `page_views` that records one row for each time a visitor accesses a page, recording the user's ip/id and the id of the page itself. I should add that the `created_at` column is of type: *timestamp*, so it includes the hours/minutes/seconds. When I try `groupBy` queries, it does not group same days together because of the seconds difference.

```
created_at         page_id       user_id
==========         =======       =======
10-11-2013            3            1
10-12 2013            5            5
10-13 2013            5            2
10-13 2013            3            4
  ...                ...          ...
```

I'd like to get results based on views/day, so I can get something like:

```
  date          views
  ====          =====
10-11-2013       15
10-12 2013       45
  ...            ...
```

I'm thinking I'll need to dig into `DB::raw()` queries to achieve this, but any insight would help greatly, thanks

Edit: Added clarification of `created_at` format.

Answer (score 99):

I believe I have found a solution to this, the key is the DATE() function in mysql, which converts a DateTime into just Date:

```
DB::table('page_views')
      ->select(DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as date'), DB::raw('count(*) as views'))
      ->groupBy('date')
      ->get();
```

However, this is not really an Laravel Eloquent solution, since this is a raw query.The following is what I came up with in Eloquent-ish syntax. The first where clause uses carbon dates to compare.

```
$visitorTraffic = PageView::where('created_at', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now->subMonth())
                            ->groupBy('date')
                            ->orderBy('date', 'DESC')
                            ->get(array(
                                DB::raw('Date(created_at) as date'),
                                DB::raw('COUNT(*) as "views"')
                            ));
```

Comment: I'm using this solution and it works great! One question I have though is if you want to group not by Date but by MONTH, you can replace:

Date(created_at) 
with 
Month(created_at)

However, what you want is to use YEAR_MONTH from MYSQL, but that won't work for me I'm afraid, I get an error. Do you see the same thing?

Comment: You could have used Eloquent `->select($columns)` and `->selectSub($query, $as)` also, to be able to skip the `DB::raw()` methods :)

Answer (score 77):

You can use Carbon (integrated in Laravel)

```
// Carbon
use Carbon\Carbon;   
$visitorTraffic = PageView::select('id', 'title', 'created_at')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(function($date) {
        return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('Y'); // grouping by years
        //return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('m'); // grouping by months
    });
```

Comment: But this groups it AFTER running the query, which means it's doing processing in php, which is much slower.

Comment: processing in PHP is not always slower but it all comes down to the requirements of your app. This IS A way to do it.

Comment: @BillGarrison it's more of wasted mysql resources. Why get 1MIL records then process them afterwards?

Comment: @Benubird Not saying this is the best way, but processing in PHP in RAM is likely to be much quicker than doing processing on your MySQL server. But possibly worth benchmarking depending on the size of your dataset.

Comment: @Sergiu The number of records you get is the same? (Assuming the `where` is added, but I can't see why it wouldn't be?)

Answer (score 32):

Here is how I do it. A short example, but made my query much more manageable

```
$visitorTraffic = PageView::where('created_at', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now->subMonth())
                        ->groupBy(DB::raw('Date(created_at)'))
                        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The `DATE()` function belongs in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 10):

Like most database problems, they should be solved by using the database.

Storing the data you want to group by and using indexes you can achieve an efficient and clear method to solve this problem.

## Create the migration

```
    $table->tinyInteger('activity_year')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->smallInteger('activity_day_of_year')->unsigned()->index();
```

## Update the Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

  use DB;
  use Carbon\Carbon;
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class PageView extends Model
  {
  public function scopePerDay($query){

     $query->groupBy('activity_year');
     $query->groupBy('activity_day_of_year');

     return $query;

  }

  public function setUpdatedAt($value)
  {   
    $date = Carbon::now();

    $this->activity_year = (int)$date->format('y');
    $this->activity_day_of_year = $date->dayOfYear;

    return parent::setUpdatedAt($value);
 }
```

## Usage

```
   $viewsPerDay = PageView::perDay()->get();
```

Comment: Old post, but didn't see this method in the answers.

Comment: Any updates to this method? @henryallsuch

Answer (score 9):

You can filter the results based on formatted date using mysql ([See here for Mysql/Mariadb help](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/date_format/)) and use something like this in laravel-5.4:

```
Model::selectRaw("COUNT(*) views, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y %m %e') date")
    ->groupBy('date')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 6):

I had same problem, I'm currently using Laravel 5.3.

I use `DATE_FORMAT()`

```
->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d')"))
```

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: I actually want to use this solution, but this code can not be correct. You've got syntax errors everywhere. Can you post functioning code? You've got "create_at" misspelled and groupBy-> which is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

```
PageView::select('id','title', DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as date'))
          ->get()
          ->groupBy('date');
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also solve this problem in following way:

```
$totalView =  View::select(DB::raw('Date(read_at) as date'), DB::raw('count(*) as Views'))
        ->groupBy(DB::raw('Date(read_at)'))
        ->orderBy(DB::raw('Date(read_at)'))
        ->get();
```

Comment: Code is always good but it also helps to add some comments/context about how it addresses the original question.

Answer (score 2):

To group data according to DATE instead of DATETIME, you can use CAST function.

```
$visitorTraffic = PageView::select('id', 'title', 'created_at')
->get()
->groupBy(DB::raw('CAST(created_at AS DATE)'));
```

Answer (score 2):

**this way work properly and I used it in many projects!**
for example I get data of views the last 30 days:

```
$viewsData = DB::table('page_views')
    ->where('page_id', $page->id)
    ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', now()->subDays(30))
    ->select(DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as data'), DB::raw('count(*) as views'))
    ->groupBy('date')
    ->get();
```

If you want to get the number of views based on different IPs, you can use the `DISTINCT` like below :

```
$viewsData = DB::table('page_views')
    ->where('page_id', $page->id)
    ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', now()->subDays(30))
    ->select(DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as data'), DB::raw('count(DISTINCT user_ip) as visitors'))
    ->groupBy('date')
    ->get();
```

You can easily customize it by manipulating the columns name

Answer (score 1):

Warning: untested code.

```
$dailyData = DB::table('page_views')
    ->select('created_at', DB::raw('count(*) as views'))
    ->groupBy('created_at')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks J.T., this should work if **created_at** could be grouped while ignoring the hours/minutes/seconds. Is it possible to group created_at by only looking at year/month/day? The **created_at** is the Laravel Schema generated timestamps.

I see 2 possible solutions which require changing the DB structure:

1. Add **Date** column that only includes Date, not DateTime.

2. Redo the eloquent model and customize the timestamp format.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an OLD Question and there are multiple answers. How ever according to the docs and my experience on laravel below is the good "Eloquent way" of handling things

In your model, add a mutator/Getter like this

```
public function getCreatedAtTimeAttribute()
{
   return $this->created_at->toDateString();
}
```

Another way is to cast the columns
in your model, populate the `$cast` array

```
$casts = [
   'created_at' => 'string'
]
```

The catch here is that you won't be able to use the Carbon on this model again since Eloquent will always cast the column into string

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Using Laravel 4.2 without Carbon

Here's how I grab the recent ten days and count each row with same day created_at timestamp.

```
$q = Spins::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d')"))
->take(10)
->get(array(
      DB::raw('Date(created_at) as date'),
      DB::raw('COUNT(*) as "views"')
  ));


foreach ($q as $day) {

  echo $day->date. " Views: " . $day->views.'<br>';

}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following code to group them by the date, since you have to parse both in the selection query and in the groupBy method:

```
$counts = DB::table('page_views')->select(DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as created_at'), DB::raw('COUNT(*) as views'))->
              groupBy(DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'))->
              get();
```

Answer (score 0):

in mysql you can add MONTH keyword having the timestamp as a parameter
in laravel you can do it like this

```
Payement::groupBy(DB::raw('MONTH(created_at)'))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I built a laravel package for making statistics : https://github.com/Ifnot/statistics

It is based on eloquent, carbon and indicators so it is really easy to use. It may be usefull for extracting date grouped indicators.

```
$statistics = Statistics::of(MyModel::query());

$statistics->date('validated_at');

$statistics->interval(Interval::$DAILY, Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2016-01-01'), Carbon::now())

$statistics->indicator('total', function($row) {
    return $row->counter;
});

$data = $statistics->make();

echo $data['2016-01-01']->total;
```

```

Answer (score 0):

Get pages views (or whatever), group my year-month-day and count for each date:

```
PageView::get()
        ->groupBy(fn($pv) => $pv->created_at->format('Y-m-d'))
        ->map(fn($date) => count($date));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $orderPayments = OrderPayment::select(
        DB::raw('MAX(id) as id'),
        DB::raw('SUM(net_total) as total_sales'),
        DB::raw('SUM(paid) as total_paid'),
        DB::raw('SUM(net_amount) as total_due_amount'),
        DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%b %d, %Y') as Day"),

    )
        ->groupBy('Day')->get();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).