# Laravel group by date to month only and get count

Tags: laravel-5

I have transactions table :

My table architecture :

```
id | item_name | quantity | created_at
```

I have try many method but its not work (link : [Laravel Eloquent get results grouped by days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603075/laravel-eloquent-get-results-grouped-by-days).

I want to display it like this :

Example :

Qty : xxx 
Month : July

Qty : xxx 
Month : October

Qty : xxx 
Month : November

How to convert from created_at column to month only grouping and display it as Word instead of numbers and then get count of grouping quantity in that month?

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603075/laravel-eloquent-get-results-grouped-by-days this may help you

Answer (score 12):

```
    $data= Transaction::select('id', 'item_name','quantity', 'created_at')
            ->get()
            ->groupBy(function($val) {
            return Carbon::parse($val->created_at)->format('m');
     });
```

Comment: Good answers *explain* as well as provide code. Consider updating your answer to include an explanation about how this code works and why it is the best option.

Comment: ErrorException in 32ea051d19391ac12447d17c2f1b05e8 line 97:
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /home/mapdipbc/resources/views/a/chart1.blade.php)

Comment: How do i do this with a join where i have 2 created_at fields?

Comment: This example fetches into a collection (in memory) then groups the data in the collection. The grouping is not done at the database query. It has the advantage of working across any database engine, but could involve moving large quantities of data from the database for post-processing (and potentially running out of memory). This example does not look like it handles the `sum()` of values for each month that it groups by, so I suspect won't actually work without some fixes.

Answer (score 5):

use eloquent date function to find only the date, you can use month to get the month or year to get only the year.

For example:

```
public function salesmonthly(Request $request){

    $monthlysales=DB::table('tbl_invs')
     ->select(DB::raw('sum(total) as total'),DB::raw('date(created_at) as dates'))
     ->groupBy('dates')
     ->orderBy('dates','desc')
    ->get();


    // dd($monthlysales);
    return view('reports.monthlysales', compact('monthlysales'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if we want to get the count based on each month in different years we use the following code

```php
$usersPerMonth = User::select(
      DB::raw('count(id) as `data`'),
      DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m') as new_date")
    )
    ->groupBy('new_date')->orderBy('new_date')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want to use carbon

```
$data= Transaction::get()
    ->groupBy(function($item) {
    return $item->created_at->month;
});
```

Comment: But it Carbon too :/

Comment: 'Created_at' is cast as a Carbon Object by default.

Answer (score 1):

**Get** transactions (or whatever), **group** by year-month and **count** for each date:

```
Transaction::get()
           ->groupBy(fn($t) => $t->created_at->format('Y-m'))
           ->map(fn($d) => count($d));
```