# Group by month producing error in laravel controller

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to execute mysql query

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM  `Mytable` WHERE `col1` = 'value' GROUP BY MONTH(Date_time)
```

Laravel statement for the same is :

```
DB::table('Mytable')->where('col1','value')->GroupBy(MONTH('Date_time'))->count();
```

As query is fine but getting error :

```
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\MONTH()
```

Any suggestion will be helpful

Comment: uh, it's pretty clear, laravel did not have `MONTH(..)` it's sql right? the easiest approach would be.. raw database..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel group by date to month only and get count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32978842/laravel-group-by-date-to-month-only-and-get-count)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
->GroupBy(MONTH('Date_time'))
```

try

```
->groupBy(DB::raw("MONTH('Date_time')"))
```

as MONTH() is a mysql function, not laravel function.

Comment: this looks like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20603414/4648586) it runs on mysql, but good idea

Comment: @jyotimishra sounds great :)

Answer (score 3):

This would be your code:

```
DB::table('Mytable')->where('col1','value')
    ->groupBy(function($date) {
        return Carbon::parse($date->Date_time)->format('m'); // grouping by months
    })
    ->count();
```

Hope this works!

Comment: this looks like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25538667/4648586) it runs on php, but good idea