# How to get all month record count in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have applied group by with with created_at column using DB query but like to do it by laravel eloquent

Output should be like this:-

```
Array
(
  [1] => 2
  [2] => 3
  [3] => 7
  [4] => 4
  [5] => 5
  [6] => 7
  [7] => 2
  [8] => 9
  [9] => 0
  [10] => 4
  [11] => 0
  [12] => 0
)
```

Please provide any help me to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Eloquent get results grouped by days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603075/laravel-eloquent-get-results-grouped-by-days)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please try the below steps:-

1. Run composer to install package:  composer require nesbot/carbon
2. On top of your code: use Carbon\Carbon;

Suppose i have Model User,

```
$users = User::select('id', 'created_at')
->get()
->groupBy(function($date) {
    //return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('Y'); // grouping by years
    return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('m'); // grouping by months
});

$usermcount = [];
$userArr = [];

foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
    $usermcount[(int)$key] = count($value);
}

for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++){
    if(!empty($usermcount[$i])){
        $userArr[$i] = $usermcount[$i];    
    }else{
        $userArr[$i] = 0;    
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you to make array like that.

Comment: Wow  Ismael  , It's work for i was looking for the same with laravel eloquent , Thanks !

Comment: Most Welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Modifing Ismael Ansari Post,

```
 $users = User::select('id', 'created_at')
        ->get()
        ->groupBy(function ($date) {
            return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('m');
        });

    $usermcount = [];
    $userArr = [];

    foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
        $usermcount[(int)$key] = count($value);
    }

    $month = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
        if (!empty($usermcount[$i])) {
            $userArr[$i]['count'] = $usermcount[$i];
        } else {
            $userArr[$i]['count'] = 0;
        }
        $userArr[$i]['month'] = $month[$i - 1];
    }

    return response()->json(array_values($userArr));
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "count": 1,
        "month": "Jan"
    },
    {
        "count": 0,
        "month": "Feb"
    },
    {
        "count": 0,
        "month": "Mar"
    },
    {
        "count": 0,
        "month": "Apr"
    },
    {
        "count": 0,
        "month": "May"
    },
    {
        "count": 0,
        "month": "Jun"
    },
    {
        "count": 0,
        "month": "Jul"
    },
    {
        "count": 0,
        "month": "Aug"
    },
    {
        "count": 0,
        "month": "Sep"
    },
    {
        "count": 0,
        "month": "Oct"
    },
    {
        "count": 0,
        "month": "Nov"
    },
    {
        "count": 0,
        "month": "Dec"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `created_at` column is DATETIME, you can group it like this

```
Entity::orderBy(...)->groupBy(DB::raw('MONTH(created_at)'))
```

You can also select the month in advance

```
Entity::select(DB::raw('MONTH(created_at) as month')->groupBy('month')->get()->keyBy('month');
```

Answer (score 0):

If we want to get the count based on each month in different years we use the following code

```
return $usersPerMonth =User::select(DB::raw('count(id) as `data`'),DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m') new_date"))
        ->groupBy('new_date')->orderBy('new_date')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can select month ,day, year wise data**

```
$data = Job::select(DB::raw("year(created_at) as year,DAY(created_at) as 
          day,MONTHNAME(created_at) as monthname"))
        ->whereYear('created_at', date('Y'))
        ->get();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).