# How to select all created_at using Laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel

I would like to select all created_at and display only one date and not all. 
For example:

```
2020-05-23 16:28:00
2020-05-23 16:35:10
2020-05-23 16:36:21
2020-05-24 14:10:26
2020-05-24 14:12:58
2020-05-24 14:14:52
2020-05-24 14:16:56
```

I would like to display them like this:

```
2020-05-23
2020-05-24
```

Comment: What have you tried? You'll need some logic to group on that specific date format, then a loop to display them. Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service; you're expected to make an attempt to solve this yourself before asking for debugging help.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT created_at FROM memberships

Comment: That's a SQL statement... How are you using this in Laravel? By show your attempt, I mean show the actual code you're using, the output, any errors, etc.

Comment: I solved using this query:
Select count(*), DATE_FORMAT(created_at,"%Y-%m-%d") as Created_Day1 FROM memberships GROUP BY Created_Day1

Comment: That's good, but please add your code to an answer below (including Laravel/PHP; a raw SQL statement doesn't answer this question). You'll be able to accept that answer in a couple days to properly close this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Eloquent get results grouped by days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603075/laravel-eloquent-get-results-grouped-by-days)

Answer (score -1):

You have the `Model` class (ex. User, Product and etc.):

```
`
 $items = Model::find(1);
 foreach ($items as $item) {
   $formattedDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($item->created_at));
   dump($formattedDate);
 }
```

`

Finally the `$formattedDate` variable has the value like this:

> 2020-05-23
>
> 2020-05-24