# Laravel group by day and paginate?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent

I want to group my posts by day, sort by latest, and include pagination for a timeline that will also contain infinite scroll for a vue spa on the frontend:

**RecordController**

```
public function userFeed($userId)
{
    $client = User::where('hashed_id', $userId)->first();   
    $records = Record::where('user_id', $client->id)->latest()->paginate(10);
    return RecordResource::collection($records);
}
```

**RecordResource**

```
class RecordResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->hashed_id,
            'owner' => new UserResource($this->owner),
            'title' => $this->title,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at->format('M d Y'),
            'comments' =>  $this->decryptedComments()
        ];
    }
}
```

[image]

I'd like the API laid out in a way where it would be easy to loop through with `v-for`:

```
[
    'Sunday' => 5,
    'Monday' => 45,
    'Tuesday' => 452,
    ...
]

<div v-for="(record, index) in records" v-bind:key="index" class="mb-10">
    <div class="card>
        <h1>{{record.title}}</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Most of the variations [to this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603075/laravel-eloquent-get-results-grouped-by-days)

Comment: `"message": "stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given",`

Comment: try `$records = Record::where('user_id', $client->id)->latest()->paginate(10)->groupBy('created_at');`

Comment: I'm still getting the same error

Comment: `stripos()` this is different error it is not related to group by

Comment: Fixed it to `Record::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->latest()->paginate(10)->groupBy('created_at');`

>"message": "array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer"

Comment: Just found this in docs:

Currently, pagination operations that use a groupBy statement cannot be executed efficiently by Laravel. If you need to use a groupBy with a paginated result set, it is recommended that you query the database and create a paginator manually.

Answer (score -1):

if you want a group by then use if before  pagination otherwise, it's not working

```
$records = Record::where('user_id', $client->id)
           ->groupBy(\DB::raw('DATE(created_at) = CURDATE()'))
           ->latest()->paginate()
```